# C++ behavior of for loops vs. while loops

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, compiler-construction

As far as I understand, when you write a for-loop similar to this one

```
for (int i = 0; i < SOME_NUM; i++) { 
  if (true)
    do_something();
  else
    do_something_else();
}
```

The time complexity of this operation is mostly affected by the `if (true)` statement because the for-loop iterations don't actually involve any comparisons of `i` to `SOME_NUM`, the compiler will just essentially run the code inside the for-loop `SOME_NUM` times.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

However if this is correct, then how do the following nested for-loops behave?

```
for (int i = 0; i < SOME_NUM; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
   do_something();
  } 
}
```

The `j` in the inner for-loop is now upper bound by `i`, a value that changes every time the loop restarts. How will the compiler compile this? Do these nested for-loops essentially behave like a for-loop with while-loop inside of it? If you're writing an algorithm that uses nested for-loops where the inner counting variable depends on the outer counting variable should you be concerned about what this will do to the complexity of your algorithm?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "time complexity" here, as that usually refers to run-time in terms of Big-Oh. And, yes the comparison in the for loop is performed, at least in the C++ sense, in a broader sense yes the optimizer can optimize it out but it has nothing to do with for vs while loop. At the end of the day it all turns into assembly, and if the comparison needs to happen there then it does. Though it may unroll it. A while and a for loop are in all practicality the same. The compiler will optimize anything it can, it can optimize both, and it's very good at it.

Comment: In this simple case I would guess the compiler would be able to detect that the inner loop is pointless and overall do_something gets called some constant amount of times. Also, the other big thing to spend time on here is the function call, however the compiler may also inline it. Yet another thing to spend time on here is branch prediction; that is if at run-time the processor predicts the if block will be taken and it is not then you flush your pipeline. However, in this case the if statement will be completely compiled out in optimized code because it's always true.

Comment: If in doubt, look at the assembly your source code generates. Debug though it. You will get a much better idea of the sorts of things the compiler can and will do, which also will depend on the sorts of instructions available in the assembly depending on your platform. If you want to see optimizations though, make sure you're compiling with them turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The time complexity of this operation is mostly affected by the if (true) statement because the for-loop iterations don't actually involve any comparisons of i to SOME_NUM, the compiler will just essentially run the code inside the for-loop SOME_NUM times. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Yes you are wrong. At the beginning of each iteration `i` is incremented and the conditional expression `i < SOME_NUM` is checked.

> If you're writing an algorithm that uses nested for-loops where the inner counting variable depends on the outer counting variable should you be concerned about what this will do to the complexity of your algorithm?

Yes. In this case you have to consider the effect of nesting. So, better you should have to remove the nesting.

Answer (score 3):

"Please correct me if I am wrong."

You are wrong.

You can add `i++` in your "first" loop somewhere and that would "break" your code. Of course a comparison of `i` to `SOME_NUM` is performed.

Comment: Is it possible for a compiler to detect that `SOME_NUM` is a constant and `i` is not being modified in the body of the `for` loop, and hence repeat the body `SOME_NUM` times?

Comment: @RSahu It is certainly possible, compiler can inline functions and unroll your loop when it sees fit.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should learn [basic loop constructs](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson3.html). A loop construct has a conditional statement which dictates if the loop will be entered and how many times will iterate.  The `if(true)` simply dictates whether the following statement(s) will be executed or not (in this case it will be since condition is always true).

In summary, the first loop will be executed `SUM_NUM` times ( `O(SUM_NUM)`), and second loop is a `O(n^2)` loop.